# Matlab binary file to Fortran

Tags: matlab, ubuntu, multidimensional-array, fortran, binaryfiles

I wrote a Matlab script that reads a binary file saved in FORTRAN (which happens to be the contents of a 4-D array). The array is stored in a Matlab variable. Next, I do the opposite operation, I wrote a Matlab script that writes the same exact 4D array to a binary file which is subsequently read in FORTRAN.

Now comes the weird part - I know they are the same because when I calculate the norm of the difference between each array I get zero, however, when I use ubuntu's diff command to compare binary files it tells me that they differ. What is going on here? [image: they differ]

In the screenshot above u_init.dat.600 is the array written in Matlab and xyz.600 is the array written in Fortran.

Comment: it might be revealing to run hexdump on them and diff the hexdumps

Comment: @george and revealing it was indeed. The only difference was in the first and last 4 bytes which makes total sense since I did not fill those locations with the record length, in any case it is inconsequential, the data is still the same.

Comment: If the data is the same, what is the problem?